# How to rename Yii's controllers using urlManager Component

Tags: php, url, yii

I need to access my controllers with another name. For example, my controller name is `*form_number_98*`, but I need to access it by calling it through URL some thing like `*/form_98*`.

All above mentioned will be done by the following line:

```
'form_<id:\d+>'=>'form_number_<id>',
```

But what if I need to access to it's view or another actions?

For example access to view with id 1

```
http://example.com/form_98/view/1
```

Which means:

```
http://example.com/form_number_98/view/id/1
```

Your answers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'showScriptName'=>false,
    'caseSensitive'=>false,
    'rules'=>array(

        '/form_number_98/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => 'form_98/<action>/'
    ),
),
```

Comment: check with my update, please try this and let me know the status

Answer (score 1):

You can achive it by using url manager. Imagine you have a controller called "SampleController" with an action called "actionSampless", then you can have something like this:

```
    'urlManager'=>array(
         'urlFormat'=>'path','showScriptName'=>false, 'caseSensitive'=>false,
         'rules'=>array(
         'test/test/*'=>'Sample/Sampless',
        //'pattern1'=>'route1', (it goes like this)
       ),
    ),
```

for more info [click here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url). read **User-friendly URLs** topic..

Hope it may help you.